# How do I find current time is between certain time period in SQL-Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, datetime, time

How can I ascertain from getdate() in SQL Server 2005 if the current time is between certain time period. If it is then have to set flag as one else two.

something like

> `getdate() timeperiod between 09:00 and 18:00 then flag =1 else flag=2`

Kindly help to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(v=sql.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

sql 2005 has datepart.  I would use that. I dont know your entire query, so here is an example of how I would use it based on what I know.

```
select timeperiod, datepart(HH,timeperiod), case 
    when datepart(HH,timeperiod)  >= 8 and datepart(HH,timeperiod)  < 9 then 1
    else 2 
    end as yourCase
    from Visit
```

Answer (score 2):

Although drewlander came up with a pretty good solution. I believe this is slightly better:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN dateadd(d,-datediff(d, 0, timeperiod), timeperiod) 
            BETWEEN '1900-01-01T08:00:00' and '1900-01-01T18:00:00'
            THEN 1 ELSE 2 END flag
FROM <table>
```

Taking the day part away from the datetime making is pretty easy to compare. This can also be used for times like 08:15 to 18:03.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /* declare @MY_syncDate datetime
    set @MY_syncDate=getdate()

*/
    SELECT case when CAST(MY_SyncDate AS TIME) BETWEEN '9:00' and '18:00' then 1 else 0 end as flag;
```

Comment: SQL Server 2005 doesn't have `TIME`